# Scala.js compilation destination

Tags: scala.js

I'm working on a Scala.js cross project where the `jvm` folder represents my server application and `js`represents my scala.js code.

Whenever i compile my scala.js code via `sbt crossJS/fastOptJS` the compiled JS ends up in `./js/target/scala-2.11/web-fastopt.js`.

I need to have this compiled JS file accessible in the resources of the server project in the `jvm` folder, so i can server it through my web application. I think i have to do something with `artifactPath` but i can't seem to get any results from my experiments thus far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply set the `artifactPath` of the `fastOptJS` task (or the `fullOptJS` task) to the (managed) resources directory of your JVM project:

```
// In the JS project's settings
artifactPath in fastOptJS in Compile :=
  (resourceManaged in jvm in Compile).value /
    ((moduleName in fastOptJS).value + "-fastopt.js"))
```

This will put it in the directory, if the you run the fastOptJS task. However, it will not be included in sbt's `resources` task and it will not automatically be triggered, if you launch your server. Therefore:

```
// In the JVM project's settings
resources in Compile += (fastOptJS in js).value.data
```

A couple of notes:

- The first step is only necessary, if your web-server does only serve specific directories. Otherwise the second one is enough, as this adds the file to the resources already; where it lies is secondary.
- <del>Setting the `crossTarget`, as in @ochrons' answer will also output all the `.class` and `.sjsir` files in the resource directory.</del>
- Have a look at Vincent Munier's [sbt-play-scalajs](https://github.com/vmunier/sbt-play-scalajs) for out-of-the-box sbt-web / Scala.js integration (it follows a slightly different approach: It copies the file from the `js` project, rather than directly placing it in the JVM project. Useful if you have multiple JVM projects).

Comment: This seems to have no effect. My `.jsSettings(artifactPath in fullOptJS := file("path/to/file/scala-project.js"))` is completely ignored when artifacts are built.

Comment: Hah! Good catch. This should be `artifactPath in fullOptJS in Compile :=`. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can configure the Scala.js SBT plugin to output the JavaScript file in folder of your choosing. For example like this:

```
// configure a specific directory for scalajs output
val scalajsOutputDir = Def.settingKey[File]("directory for javascript files output by scalajs")

// make all JS builds use the output dir defined later
lazy val js2jvmSettings = Seq(fastOptJS, fullOptJS, packageJSDependencies) map { packageJSKey =>
  crossTarget in(js, Compile, packageJSKey) := scalajsOutputDir.value
}
// instantiate the JVM project for SBT with some additional settings
lazy val jvm: Project = sharedProject.jvm.settings(js2jvmSettings: _*).settings(
  // scala.js output is directed under "web/js" dir in the jvm project
  scalajsOutputDir := (classDirectory in Compile).value / "web" / "js",
```

This will also store -jsdeps.js and .js.map files in the same folder, in case you want to use those in your web app.

For a more complete example, check out [this tutorial](https://github.com/ochrons/scalajs-spa-tutorial) which addresses many other issues of creating a more complex Scala.js application.

Comment: what is sharedProject ?

Comment: sharedProject in this context means a Scala.js cross project such as:
`lazy val shared = (crossProject.crossType(CrossType.Pure) in file("shared"))`